# Despite requiring dotenv to load environment variables from .env file, they still get loaded from the machine /etc/environment

Tags: environment-variables, environment, development-environment, production-environment, dotenv

I am using **dotenv** to load environment variables from **.env** file when I am in the development environment.

> server.js

```
const { config } = require("dotenv");
config();
console.log(" ~ file: server.js ~ line 7 ~ config()", config());
console.log(
  " ~ file: server.js ~ line 10 ~ process.env.ADMIN_DB_URI",
  process.env.ADMIN_DB_URI
);
```

This is what gets logged:

```
 ~ file: server.js ~ line 7 ~ config() {
  parsed: {
    ADMIN_DB_URI: 'URI_THAT_IS_SAVED_IN_DOTENV_FILE',
  }
}
 ~ file: server.js ~ line 10 ~ process.env.ADMIN_DB_URI URI_THAT_IS_SAVED_IN_/ETC_/ENVIRONMENT_FILE
```

So apparently loading the environment variable `ADMIN_DB_URI` from **.env** file works correctly as you can see in the log of the result of executing the `config` function.

But, when I log process.env.ADMIN_DB_URI right after that, it logs the value that is stored in `/etc/environment`.

This is confusing and I don't understand why it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

After a few days I found out why this happens.
If you have an environment variable that exists both in `.env` file and in `/etc/environment`, nodejs will load the one `/etc/environment`.

So all I had to do is rename the variable in `.env`.